# How to add time with timezone column using knex js?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using knex version "^2.3.0" and Postgresql.
When using **time** method it creates column with data type **time without timezone** but that's not what I want.

Is there any way that I can create a column with data type **time with timezone**?
Thanks in advance.

```
      table.time('timeColumnWithTimezone'); // but creates time without timezone
```

Comment: Is it possible to use datetime column instead? Seems knex supports timezones for it (https://knexjs.org/guide/schema-builder.html#datetime)

Comment: I'd also check if `time` supports `useTz` option as datetime and timestamp do

Comment: @vitkarpov I also thought about using datetime but it wont make sense to save date fields in my use case.

Comment: what about timestamp column?

Comment: I see latest knex supports datetime and timestamp (https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/4494113187cb246d402e1d8747f9bea630d38aa3/lib/dialects/postgres/schema/pg-columncompiler.js#L77-L95)

Comment: I need to save only the time value and timezone. I'm not sure, if I use a timestamp column and ignore the date value and use the time value will it create any issues?

Comment: Storing date and time zone then ignoring the date MAY create issues, but NOT as many as just *time with time zone*. Reference [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES).  *... We do not recommend using the type time with time zone ...* Further keep in mind that Postgres does not store the timezone. It is converted to/from UTC for the local time zone.